# History of Hashkeim vs. Bo

Tags: history, torah-reading, plagues-makkos, bo, va-eira

I learned in [this book](https://www.magnespress.co.il/book/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-3250) that in some ancient traditions, they started a new parsha at [Hashkeim](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.9.13) (barad) instead of at [Bo](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.10.1) (arbeh), as I'm used to.  (This is a variation of the minhag to read the whole Torah in one year, I am not referring to the Israeli minhag to do it in 3 years.)

Where can I find more information on history of these different divisions?  Are there still communities that start at Hashkeim, and if not, how long did that minhag survive?  Was it ever the dominant minhag, and if so, when did Bo take over?  Did poskim record the reasons for one division or the other?

I'm particularly interested because Hashkeim is the beginning of a new set of makkos באח"ב and, on a simple level, makes more sense as the start of a parsha.  I've heard people connect the 7-3 division of makkos to kabbalah and sefiros, but that can't be the whole story - the [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Order_of_Prayer.5.4) records our minhag to start at Bo and wouldn't have used that reason.

Comment: https://faculty.biu.ac.il/~ofery/papers/Chapter%20I.pdf